# How to change start address of heap for process virtual memory

Tags: arm, embedded-linux

I am porting a code from one board to another (arm processor from imx27 to imx6) and have a requirement that the heap must start from address greater than 1GB, stack and other process memory is mapped above 1 GB but some areas are mapped under 1 GB.

The requirement is because of internal code logic in the application where the data is in flash or RAM is detected that way, hence cannot change it.

I wrote a small program and checked the map file for your reference in 2 boards.

Boards B has the desired range and Board A is where i want the change.

***Board A:***
/home # cat /proc/1133/maps
00008000-00009000 r-xp 00000000 1f:05 12         /home/mem
00010000-00011000 rw-p 00000000 1f:05 12         /home/mem
**00011000-00032000** rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
........................................
7eda3000-7edc4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]

***Board B:***
/home # cat /proc/1233/maps
80000000-8020e000 r-xp 00000000 1f:04 33         /home/mem
80216000-8021a000 rw-p 0020e000 1f:04 33         /home/mem
**8021a000-80715000** rwxp 8021a000 00:00 0          [heap]
........................................
becd8000-beced000 rwxp befeb000 00:00 0          [stack]

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use some access layer for flash?

Comment: Agreed but right now there is no option. Since it is spread across full code base and making such a change is not possible. Access layer is done via mtd (accessed as an mtd partition but with the offset in flash)

Comment: If you would say that you were porting this "app" from a MCU to Linux, I could understand the requirements. However I don't see how your "app" works under Linux with virtual memory.

Comment: The code was in RTOS earlier and there the addressing was absolute and hence the address of flash was assumed from 0 to say 100 MB and RAM was from 100MB to 200MB. When the code was ported to Linux the virtual memory came into picture. Hence the address of area in flash still considered as 0 to 100 MB but virtual address of process memory (a pointer malloc'd) uses the address from 0 to 100 MB. This is a wrong assumption in code but the change is costly and easier way through is to have virtual address of heap staring above 100 MB.

Comment: Try to create a linker file where you set heap (data) address as you want.

Comment: Thanks @auslen it worked :)... I could not find the default location of linker scripthence for testing it i did   gcc test.c -o test.o -Wl,-verbose and captured the internal linker script used and modified the offsets. then compiled gcc test.c -o test.o -T test.lds (where test.lds is the modified linker script). This worked like a charm. Need one help. Where is the defualt internal linker script located for gcc and where will it be for cross compiler in tool chains?

Comment: -Wl,-verbose didn't show the default location?

Comment: It used internal linker script which is part of the cross compiler toolchains ld itself. Check with grep in that file.